# Find which column a value belongs to in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 9 columns with names in them and a list of 400 names. How do I populate the column numbers associated with each name without having to go through each name location individually. Kindly advice.

[image]

This is an example of what I am looking for. Get the column numbers for a list of names I have in a column.

Comment: Please explain more about what you want and in what sense you want to "populate the column numbers associated with each name". Please [update](https://superuser.com/posts/1370273/edit) your answer to include sample data and the output you want.

Comment: @AFH I have updated the question

Comment: That's very clear, thanks, and Scott has your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE()

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:$H$4)/($A$2:$H$4=K2),1)
```

This will create an array of column numbers and `#DIV/0` errors.  The AGGREGATE will ignore the errors and return the lowest column number where the value is found.

[image]